# Можно ли создать экземпляр абстрактного класса с помощью анонимного класса?

Tags: java, вложенные-классы

Коллега поделилась историей своего собеседования. Интервьюер задал вопрос по `Java`:

> Как получить экземпляр абстрактного класса?

Она естественно ответила:

> Никак. Нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса.

Он с ней не согласился, заявив, что мы можем сделать это с помощью анонимного класса.

По его мнению, в представленном ниже примере, в переменной `ac` окажется ссылка на экземпляр абстрактного класса `AbstractClass`, то есть с помощью анонимного класса будет получен экземпляр абстрактного класса.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    abstract void doSomething();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractClass ac = new AbstractClass() {
            @Override
            void doSomething() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Лично я **не согласен** с его мнением, считаю что таким образом будет получен экземпляр анонимного класса, но не абстрактного. По сути анонимный класс в этом случае - это уже наследник.